# Convolve and Plotting

Tags: plotting, convolution

I want to convolute my equation with Gaussian function.I used following code for it but it does not give the output? How do I correct it

```
 μ = 0; σ = 0.033;
 Eg = 0.52; Eb = 0.070
 h3 = Convolve[1/(E^((x - μ)^2/(2*σ^2))*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*σ)), 
     (2*Pi* Eb^0.5*UnitStep[x - Eg])/(1 - Exp[(-2*Pi)*(Eb/(x - Eg))^0.5]), x, y]
 g = Plot[h3, {y, 0, 1.8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It appears that Mathematica cannot perform the integral symbolically.  Do you have reason to believe that a symbolic solution exists?

Comment: The "x"should be greater than X.How should I define it? Could you tell me?

Comment: Include the option, `Assumptions -> x > X`.

Comment: Do I need to input it as a separate input ?

Comment: It is an option for `Convolve`.  For instance, use `Convolve[1/(E^((x - μ)^2/(2*σ^2))*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*σ)), ((2*Pi* Eb^0.5*UnitStep[x - Eg])/(1 - Exp[(-2*Pi)*(Eb/(x - Eg))^0.5]), x, y, Assumptions -> x > X]`.  Whether doing so will help obtain a solution seems unlikely to me..

Comment: I got input as out put? What does it mean?is there any method to get the solution?

Comment: Please see my very first comment above.

Comment: I did integral symbolically,when I remove x from the exponential function,it produces out put.